# Complex database situation

Tags: mysql, view

I'm using a open source ERP (Dollibar) so I cannot modify the source code. 
In my architecture I use several ERP installations (several databases) and 
I have a very big product table (> 3.000.000 records). This product table must be shared by all databases

At the moment:

- I deleted the product table from each original database
- put the product table in an external database
- I create a VIEW (MEMORY TABLE) to this table in each original database. Obviously the view name is the same of the deleted product table

This solution seems to work, all single installation share now the product table.

The problem is now to allow each installation to add specific product, products that need not be seen outside of the single installation itself.

I thought to create many "local_product" table and to JOIN to the shared product table with a UNION view.
This is working too, but:

- this last VIEW is read-only
- is not possible to put triggers on this wiew in order to update the "local_product" table

I'm on a blnid alley?

Thanks

Comment: `open source ERP (Dollibar) so I cannot modify the source code` ... What? Yes you can, according to [their license](https://wiki.dolibarr.org/index.php/FAQ_What_is_Dolibarr_licence_%3F) ... unless there is some other reason.

Comment: You are right, Paul, but if I modify the code, I will not use the future "standard" release. I would like to avoid that..

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Anyway, this question might be better to ask https://dba.stackexchange.com.  I cannot find any documentation as to whether a trigger can be applied to a memory table (or not).  Have you tried and it errors?

Comment: As I can see, in MySQL triggers cannot be used in memory table.
I will turn the question in other  forum. Thanks.